# What is the state of ElementRef when it's available in components constructor

Tags: javascript, angular

I can get access to `ElementRef` in components constructor:

```
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(element: ElementRef) {
       element.nativeElement
```

What is the state of this DOM element:

1) in terms of DOM - is it put in the DOM already? Is it rendered? Are it's child components DOM elements created and appended?

2) in terms of child components lifecycle - what stages have child components gone through - onInit, afterContentInit etc.?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Internally each Angular component is represented as an element and a directive. You can read more about it in the [Here is why you will not find components inside Angular](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-why-you-will-not-find-components-inside-angular-bdaf204d955c).

The `elementRef` that you can inject into the constructor is actually the element used to host a component. Now to your questions.

> 1) in terms of DOM - is it put in the DOM already? Is it rendered? Are
>   it's child components DOM elements created and appended?

Yes, it's created and appended to the parent DOM element. It's not yet rendered as the process of bootstrapping components synchronous so a browser doesn't have a chance for repaint. No, its child components are not created  yet.

> 2) in terms of child components lifecycle - what stages have child
>   components gone through - onInit, afterContentInit etc.?

All lifecycle hooks are part of change detection. Read more in [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f). And the components tree is created before change detection. So no lifecycle hooks has been triggered for this component and as I said above no children have been created yet.

Answer (score 6):

1) `ElementRef.nativeElement` is avalable when `ngAfterViewInit()` is called.

2) If you mean transcluded children, then it is `ngAfterContentInit()`.

Comment: can you add more details please? I'm looking for answers to specific questions regarding each of the areas (DOM and angular cycles)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The `ElementRef` is available immediately when you inject it, and `nativeElement` **is** the DOM element. When the mentioned callbacks are called, the DOM element is available, before that it is just `null`. That's all there is about `nativeElement`.

Comment: _The ElementRef is available immediately when you inject it,_ - yes, but it can be in the state of simply created by angular in memory, or already appended to the `document` tree, or even rendered on UI.

Comment: No, `ElementRef` is not rendered, but when the related element is rendered `ElementRef.nativeElement` is set to a refererence to the DOM element, immediately before `ngAfterViewInit()` is called for view elements, and immediately before `ngAfterContentInit()` for transcluded elements.

Comment: I think `ElementRef` is confusing here, I'm talking of course about `ElementRef.nativeElement` in terms of the state

Comment: But I think my explanation should now cover your questions. I just tried to be unambiguous.

Comment: yeah, thanks, it answers in terms of lifecycle hooks... I'll probably split the question into two separate questions. Give me some time to understand the hooks side of your answer :)

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html should give you all the info.

Comment: hey, I just added [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45392136/2545680). You might find information in it interesting.